# Dynamic image loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that lists users, each user has a profile image. The page loads very slow since all the profile images are loaded. Is there a way of only loading the profile images that are visible and then dynamically loading the other profile images as they are shown when the users scrolls down the page? And/or is it better to dynamically build CSS style blocks where the profile images are all located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this Asynchronous Image Loader Plugin

http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects

([GitHub Project](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL))

Comment: Now project is [on github](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL) as I see. And author project page is [http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects).